# How do I keep an overlay in the same position on screen at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I haven't found an answer that worked for me - I'm hoping someone can help. My CSS skills are lacking...

I have a video displaying in a web page that will have a text overlay. My issue is that on my screen, the overlay is in the correct position. When this is projected onto a big screen, the overlay is in the wrong position.

What is the best strategy to use to solve this issue? Positioning overlay in CSS? Using panels? Code follows...

CSS:

```
.video {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:50%;
        height:80%;   
    }

    #vidPlayer {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:-100px;
            left:0px;        
            width:100%; 
            display:block;
            z-index:99;
        }

    .overlayLabel {
        font-size:xx-large;
        font-weight:bolder;
        font-style:italic;
        color:antiquewhite;
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        bottom:50px;
        left:100px;
        width:900px;  
        border:2px solid red;      
        z-index:2147483647;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <article class="video">      
        <video id="vidPlayer" title="My Video" >
            <source src="Media/MyVideo.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <asp:Label ID="lblWinner" runat="server" Text="Test Overlay" CssClass="overlayLabel"></asp:Label>      

    </article>
</div>
```

---

My changes fixed the following problems I had:

- the CSS to display an overlay with text over the video (text set dynamically)
- the video is now the proper size
- the overlay is positioned correctly regardless of screen size

  ```
  .video {
      position:relative;
      width:100%;
      height:auto;   
  }

  #vidPlayer {
      z-index:99;
      position:relative;     
      width:100%; 
      height:100%;
      }

  .overlayLabel { 
      z-index:2147483647;
      position:absolute;    
      background-image:url("Images/test.png");
      -webkit-transform: rotate(13deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(13deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(13deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(13deg);
      transform: rotate(13deg);
      font-size:xx-large;
      font-weight:bolder;
      text-align:center; 
      color:black;       
      bottom:44%;
      left:37%;
      width:30%; 
      height:24%;      
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are wanting it to look like?  Or create a jsfiddle with what you are seeing?  When I paste your code, its just hanging off the bottom of the page... which I doubt is what you are looking for.  A screenshot of what you want would be best.

Comment: That is sort of what I want (yes, I am aware of how pathetic this is). There is too much black space around the video player (trying to get rid of that without going full screen). I need the overlay at a specific part of the video, displaying text that is calculated in the code behind. If there is a better way, please enlighten me!

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle ( if your problem is still unsolved )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your design responsive.

You can either use CSS media queries, so there are different style rules, at different resolutions ( widths ), for positioning your labels/text. See [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Or you can use responsive units like **%, vh, vw** instead of **px** for positioning.

I prefer using media queries.

Comment: This page will only be used displayed on a projector at an event. I don't know the resolution of the screen used at the event, and I won't have access to the equipment until the day of. Would the responsive units be the best for this?

Comment: I ended up taking a lot of stuff out and starting from the beginning...I didn't need a lot of the things I had in the CSS. I did end up using % instead of px for the width and positioning and that helped a lot.

Comment: Its an honor for me to help someone